# To determine whether the 18650 li-ion is protected battery

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

How to do correct test and determine whether a 18650 Li-ion is protected or non-protected battery?

Comment: Check the datasheet?

Comment: If it has a consumer label it is probably protected. If it doesn't, it is probably not. Samsung does not sell protected cells. Other companies may buy samsung cells and add protection, but they will also put their log on the cell. Same goes for Sony, Panasonic, etc. They don't cell protected cells.

Answer (score 1):

A protected LiIon battery will disconnect the output of the battery to prevent overdischarge. It also has overload protection. You could do one of the following:

- Discharge the battery using a resistor. If the battery voltage drops below 2.3V, then the battery is not protected.
- This test is only for the bold: Connect a slow blow fuse, e.g. 500mA directly in parallel with the battery. If the fuse survives, then the battery is protected, because the protection circuit should protect the battery from short circuits.